# mysql-binlog-connector-java - Could not find first log file name in binary log index file

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I am doing a POC on this library, and I am having some difficulties setting it up. I have an extremly simple MySQL setup:
- a single VM (no master-slaves)
- centos 7
- MySQL version 5.7

Here is the code I have until now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BinaryLogClient client = new BinaryLogClient("***.***.***.***", 3306, "****", "******");
    client.setBinlogFilename("/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin");

    client.registerLifecycleListener(new BinaryLogClient.LifecycleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnect(BinaryLogClient binaryLogClient) {
            System.out.println("OnConnect()");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCommunicationFailure(BinaryLogClient binaryLogClient, Exception e) {
            System.out.println("OnCommunicationFailure()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override
        public void onEventDeserializationFailure(BinaryLogClient binaryLogClient, Exception e) {
            System.out.println("OnEventDeserialize()");
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnect(BinaryLogClient binaryLogClient) {
            System.out.println("OnDisconnect()");
        }
    });

    client.registerEventListener(new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) {
            System.out.println(event.toString());
        }
    });
    client.connect();
}
```

When running this code I get the following output:

> OnCommunicationFailure()
>   com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.network.ServerException: Could not find first log file name in binary log index file
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:882)
>       at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:559)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:40)

My MySQL configuration file content:

> [mysqld]
>
> datadir=/var/lib/mysql socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
>
> symbolic-links=0
>
> log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
>
> server_id=1
>
> log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin
>
> pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>
> bind-address=***.***.***.***

The contents of my log directory is as follows:

```
[mysql]# ls
error.log  mysql-bin.000001  mysql-bin.index  mysqld.log
```

and the contents of mysql-bin.index is of course:

```
/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.000001
```

All of the online solutions for this problem refer to a master slave configurations and the solutions are accordingly - help anyone?:)

Comment: could you able to find any workaround for this issue..?